# Copy-Item -Recurse skips Creation of one sub-directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to copy all files with all subdirectories to another machine (using a WinRM session) and the copy part of my script looks like this:

```
$sourceDir = "C:\Build\Application1"
$targetDir = "C:\Install\Application1"
Copy-Item -ToSession $session -Path $sourceDir\* -Destination $targetDir -Recurse -Force
```

`$sourceDir` contains two subdirectories:

```
C:\Build\Application1 (3 files)
             |
             +--- Application Files (empty)
                         |
                         +--- Application_2016_12_10_2 (10 files)
```

**Scenario 1**

If the folder `Application1` does **not exist** yet in `C:\Install`, the destination folder structure looks like this after executing my script:

```
C:\Install\Application1 (3 files)
             |
             +--- Application_2016_12_10_2 (10 files)
```

**Scenario 2**

If the folder `Application1` already **exists** in `C:\Install`, the destination folder structure looks like this as expected:

```
C:\Install\Application1 (3 files)
             |
             +--- Application Files (empty)
                         |
                         +--- Application_2016_12_10_2 (10 files)
```

Why is my script not creating the folder `Application Files` in the first scenario? Can someone clarify?

I'm using Powershell 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the issue what you are facing is because you are telling powershell to copy the items from the **sourcedir\*** . As a result, it is looking for the content of it.

So just use this directly and it will work :

```
$sourceDir = "C:\Build\Application1"
$targetDir = "C:\Install\Application1"
Copy-Item -ToSession $session -Path $sourceDir -Destination $targetDir -Recurse -Force
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That was the Problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @Marc.. Happy to help :)